# Auto reconnect to Binance Websocket after 24 hours

Tags: websocket, binance, java-websocket

I'm currently experimenting on Binance Websocket (https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#websocket-market-streams), streaming the candlestick data for processing.

As documented, the stream will randomly close after 24 hours. What's the best way to continue the session without interruption? I mean disconnect/reconnect after 23 hours so the program will continue without losing its state.

Here's what I did. I'm using the binance-java-api https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api.

And here's how I connect:

```
BinanceApiWebSocketClient client =
    BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance(
            appConfig.getApiKey(),
            appConfig.getApiSecret(),
            appConfig.isUseTestNet(),
            appConfig.isUseTestNet())
        .newWebSocketClient();


client.onCandlestickEvent(cryptoPair.toLowerCase(), getCandlestickInterval(),
    new BinanceApiCallback<>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(final CandlestickEvent evt) {}
```

Comment: You don’t specify how you connect to the Websocket so it won’t be possible to help you much. Moreover you should explain what is the exact issue you have with reconnecting automatically.

Comment: The "best" way is the one you'll try last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I have used a scheduler/timer to reconnect the session every 12 hours. Since I'm using the Quarkus framework, it's readily available.

Solution:
SessionManager class:

```
@Singleton
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SessionManagerScheduler {

  final BinanceEventHandler binanceEventHandler;

  @Scheduled(cron = "0 2 */12 * * ?")
  public void reconnectSession() {

    log.info("Keep-Alive: Binance Session Via WebSocket -------------------------");

    binanceEventHandler.timeout();
  }
}
```

The Binance event handler:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BinanceEventHandler {

  final AppConfig appConfig;
  final CandlestickAccumulator candlestickAccumulator;
  final CandlestickMapper candlestickMapper;

  private Closeable candleStream = null;

  public void start() {

    streamCandleEvent();
  }

  public void timeout() {

    try {
      candleStream.close();

      streamCandleEvent();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  private void streamCandleEvent() {

    String cryptoPair = String.join(",", appConfig.getCryptoPairs());

    log.info("Start listening to cryptoPair={}", cryptoPair);

    candleStream = getClient().onCandlestickEvent(cryptoPair.toLowerCase(), getCandlestickInterval(),
        new BinanceApiCallback<>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(final CandlestickEvent evt) {

            if (!evt.getBarFinal()) {
              return;
            }

            log.debug("Processing cryptoPair={}, event={}", cryptoPair, evt);

            Candlestick candlestick = candlestickMapper.asCandleStick(evt);

            candlestickAccumulator.processCandlestickEvent(candlestick);
          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(final Throwable cause) {

            Application.hasError = true;
            log.error("Fail connecting to Binance API {}", cause.getMessage());
          }
        }
    );
  }

  private BinanceApiWebSocketClient getClient() {

    return BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance(
            appConfig.getApiKey(),
            appConfig.getApiSecret(),
            appConfig.isUseTestNet(),
            appConfig.isUseTestNet())
        .newWebSocketClient();
  }

  private CandlestickInterval getCandlestickInterval() {
    return CandlestickInterval.valueOf(appConfig.getCandlestickInterval());
  }
}
```